# Blade engine: print triple curly braces

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I know how to print double curly braces in Laravel: `@{{ }}`.

But how can I print triple curly braces? My first thought of adding an @ before does not work, Laravel still tries to interpret it.

Is there an easy way without encoding the braces to HTML entities?

Comment: can u provide an example of what you are trying to achieve (especially your current code snippet and the expected vs. real output)?

Comment: I want to print triple curly braces in a view.

Wanted output: `{{{text}}}`  
Not working code: `@{{{text}}}`

Comment: This has been fixed in the framework. See my answer below for more information.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Update

Very recently, a [pull request](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/9574) was merged that fixes this problem!!
As of **Laravel 5.1.7** it is possible to use the `@` sign as expected:

```
@{{{ ... }}}
```

---

#### Original Answer

The least ugly workaround I found up until now is to escape the first two brackets as normal and adding an invisible between them and the third bracket:

```
@{{&zwnj;{test}}}
```

I'll investigate further and update this answer if I find something better...

Answer (score 12):

This is the easiest way. Use HTML entities to escape curly braces. Tested in Laravel 5.
See here for the list of HTML entities. [HTML Entities](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html)

**Code**

```
&#123;&#123;&#123;text&#125;&#125;&#125;
```

**Output**

```
{{{text}}}
```

Comment: I'll just use `&#123;&#123;&#123;text&#125;&#125;&#125;` without the curly brackets. Seems to be the easiest solution to me. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it simply outputs the characters as they are escaped...

Comment: need to use `{!! '&#123;&#123;&#123;' . 'text'. '&#125;&#125;&#125;' !!}`

Answer (score 4):

Use this if you just want to print them:

```
{{ '{{{' }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your superfast answer. But this is not working correctly: `{{ '{{{text}}}' }}`.  
Nothing gets printed.

Comment: Maybe a little weird but this works: {{ '{{{text' .  '}' . '}' . '}' }}

Answer (score 2):

One more way is as following

```
{@{{Text}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue trying to render some raw HTML using Vue.js in laravel 4.2. For me the easiest solution was to just to use a simple php echo statement in the blade template:

```
<?php echo '{{{ text }}}'; ?>
```

Did the trick for me.

Comment: Also if the php rendering engine still picks them up inside the echo (as ours did  yesterday) you can break it up:  <?php echo '{' . '{' . '{ text }' .'}' . '}'; ?> to pass  {{{ text }}} to your JavaScript