# Laravel & Algolia Instantsearch.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade, algolia

I'm getting the error:

> Use of undefined constant image - assumed 'image' (View: C:\laragon\www\project\resources\views\home.blade.php)

When I try to display my Algolia hit template which is:

```
<script type="text/html" id="hit-template">
<div class="hit">
<div class="hit-image">
  <img src="{{image}}" alt="{{name}}">
</div>
<div class="hit-content">
  <h3 class="hit-price">${{price}}</h3>
  <h2 class="hit-name">{{{_highlightResult.name.value}}}</h2>
  <p class="hit-description">{{{_highlightResult.description.value}}}</p>
</div>
</div>
</script>
```

But it looks like Laravel thinks I'm trying to output info with Blade.
Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct about the fact that `blade` considers curly braces as being part of its template.

It seems like you can use this syntax to tell blade to not try to interpolate:

```
@{{ ... }}
```

and

```
@{{{ ... }}}
```

Source: [Blade engine: print triple curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29621970/blade-engine-print-triple-curly-braces) .