# LARAVEL - How to print double curly brackets

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a blog where I can write tutorials and adding code and such...
My editor works with ALL the codes so far, except when I try to write laravel variables with double braces...

For example, in my textarea i write: {{ something }}
this is saved in the database but the "edit success page" doesn't show anything
then when I try to print this in my website, I can't see what's inside the brackets

I tried replacing { with `&#123;` and } with `&#125;`, but when I try to print Laravel AGAIN removes the content inside... this means that laravel actually tries to use this variables even if they SEEM like double braces?

How can I actually print this without Laravel trying to read it as variables?
Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want your data to be escaped then use {!! !!}. This should work.

Comment: But actually, as far as I remember you need to use double curly brackets like this: **@{{ content }}**  in order to print them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both the entities and the @ sign.  Put the symbol within quotes or use the @before the brackets.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29621970/blade-engine-print-triple-curly-braces)

and [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/9574)

and [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-escape-double-curly-braces-in-a-blade-template)

for a few places where others have gone through the same issues.

Answer (score -1):

You have to place your {{variable }} between text-area tag or else it won't print.
Or
You can also use simple php to print the value of variable like

`<textarea> 
    {{ $vadiable }}
 </textarea>`